How to extract a frame from an INSV format 360 video using Python
I have a 360 video captured with an Insta360 X3, which is in the INSV format. I would like to extract a frame from this video using Python, FFmpeg, or any other suitable tool, without using Insta360 Studio to export the video to MP4 first.
Here is what I have tried so far:
FFmpeg: I attempted to use FFmpeg to directly convert the INSV file to images, but I encountered errors, possibly due to the proprietary nature of the INSV format.
ffmpeg -i input.insv -vf "select=eq(n,0)" -q:v 3 output.jpg

This command did not work as expected and produced an error.
Python Libraries: I looked into various Python libraries such as OpenCV and MoviePy, but they do not natively support INSV format.
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('input.insv')
success, frame = cap.read()
if success:
    cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', frame)


This code did not work, as OpenCV could not open the INSV file.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to directly extract frames from an INSV format 360 video using Python, FFmpeg, or any other tool?

if it is proprietary format then it may be problem to find module which can work with this. Did you search it in Google?

What is the FFmpeg error?

Unable to choose an output format for 'select=eq(n,0)'; use a standard extension for the filename or specify the format manually.
Error initializing the muxer for select=eq(n,0): Invalid argument
Error opening output file select=eq(n,0).
Error opening output files: Invalid argument

Instead of capturing frames directly from the .insv file, it’s better to first export the .insv to .mp4 using Insta360 Studio. Once you have the .mp4, you can extract the frames as .jpg files using OpenCV, just like you did before.
This method ensures you get the correct panoramic (360-degree) frames. After extracting the frames, you can test them by uploading to this online panoramic viewer:
https://renderstuff.com/tools/360-panorama-web-viewer/
